# JFrame freezes when I run a bot

Tags: java

This is a spam bot it writes a string that you input when you press the button, but when I press the run button the JFrame freezes and I can't press it to stop it and it keeps on running. I want to be able to toggle the button while its running, any suggestions?

```
    import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Main extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("SPAM BOT");
    JTextField txt = new JTextField(20);
    JToggleButton btn = new JToggleButton("START");

    Font font = new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 20);
    Font font2 = new Font("Wildcard", Font.BOLD, 20);

    public Main(){
        sendUI();
    }

    public void sendUI(){
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setSize(375, 115);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.add(txt);
        frame.add(btn);

        txt.setFont(font);              
        btn.setFont(font2);

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {            

                String str = txt.getText().toString();                                                              
                if(btn.isSelected()){
                    btn.setText("STOP");       
                    write(true, str);
                    btn.setSelected(false);

                }else{                      
                    btn.setText("START");
                    write(false, str);
                }

            }
        });

    }

    public void write(boolean typing, final String str){
        while(typing==true){
            SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>(){

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    try {
                        Bot bot = new Bot();
                        //bot.type(str + " ");
                        System.out.println("done");
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }catch (AWTException e) {}
                    return null;
                }
            };
            worker.execute();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

        try{
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        }catch(Exception e){}

        Main mo = new Main();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because everything is running in one thread. You should consider creating another thread for your bot:)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Why in your opinion it is not the answer for OPs post? The answer is putting most of his bot logic in separate thread so I don't understand where you see a problem in my comment. I'm not critiquing his post or the issue he have.

Comment: You may be correct, but, as is, your answer would be more appropriate as a comment. You may want to elaborate a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Generally processes such as this, or anything related to networking should run on a separate thread to prevent "Freezing". I like to keep all of my calculations on a separate thread when working with Java Swing to create a responsive interface.

[This Oracle Trail is right down your ally.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) It provides a whole section on providing a responsive GUI including background tasks and thread pools. Reading through it will definitely solve your problem.